# How to wait on Cypress task completion?

Tags: cypress

I have a test that gets some data through a task:

```js
it('cleans the company', () => {
    cy.task('getKey').then((data: Key) => {
        key = data;
    });
    cy.task('getCompany').then((data: any) => {
        company = data;
    });
    cy.wait(1500).then(() => {
```

The functions in the task:

```js
getKey: () => {
    return key;
},

getCompany: () => {
    return company;
},
```

Is it possible to wait for the tasks to complete rather than using a timed wait?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are asking about accessing the task results later in the test.
As the Cypress commands (including tasks) are [asynchronous](https://learn.cypress.io/cypress-fundamentals/understanding-the-asynchronous-nature-of-cypress), it's impossible to get something like this to work:

```js
    let key;
    cy.task('getKey').then((data: Key) => {
        key = data;
    });
    cy.log(key); // key is yet not computed and so is undefined at this moment
```

To use the task result later in the test, you have to use any of cy `then` callback:

```js
    let key;
    cy.task('getKey').then((data: Key) => {
        key = data;
    });
    cy.then(() => {
      cy.log(key); // key will be computed at this time 
    });
```

Or you can call the task in a `before`/`beforeEach` hook and Cypress will execute the task before any of `it` statement:

```js
let key;
before(() => {
    cy.task('getKey').then((data: Key) => {
        key = data;
    });
})

it('test #1', () => {
  cy.log(key); // key will be computed at this time 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you add timeouts to the tasks.

```js
cy.task('getKey', {timeout: 9000}).then((data: Key) => {
  key = data
})
cy.task('getCompany', {timeout: 9000}).then((data: any) => {
  company = data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tasks](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Tasks-must-end) that do not end are not supported. There is a [configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Set-timeout-in-the-test-configuration) for tasks specific commands which you can set at test, suite, or global level.

```js
it('cleans the company', { taskTimeout: 90_000 }, () => {
    cy.task('getKey').then((data: Key) => {
        key = data;
    });
    cy.task('getCompany').then((data: any) => {
        company = data;
    });
    // rest of test
})
```